# MUI component styling changes upon initialization of the Navigate component React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-router

I am implementing react router in my application and have recently come upon and unusual side-effect when implementing the `<Navigate to="/">` (going to `<AthleteHomepage />`) component upon state change. Currently, I have not implemented the functionality for dynamic state change and am simply trying to get the `<Navigate to=""/>` component to execute the expected behavior. When the `<Navigate to="/">` component is initialized it navigates to the expected component (`<AthleteHomepage />`). However, the styling of `<AthleteHomepage />` changes quite a bit (colors change, buttons are misplaced, etc). This does not happen when I send a get request in the browser to that route, invoking the specific `<Route>` for that component. I am curious as to why this might be and if anyone has come across this issue before?

I am using Webpack dev server and am proxying requests to the backend. I am not sure if there are any issues in this regard. However, I have already set `historyApiFallback: true` so that my routes will work. Below is a snippet from my code. Also, I have included my github repo with the full code for more context.

```
const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("t");
  return (
    <Box>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            user ? <AthleteHomepage /> : <Navigate from="/" to="/login" />
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/login"
          element={user ? <Navigate from="/login" to="/" /> : <LoginPage />}
        />
      </Routes>
      <FooterNavContent />
    </Box>
  );
};

// create context to give child props access to values
export const AthleteHomePageContext = createContext(null);
// reducer for handling modal state changes
const modalStateReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "changeModalVisibility":
      return { open: !state.open, workoutValue: state.workoutValue };
    case "setWorkoutType":
      return { open: state.open, workoutValue: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

// workouts reducer handling data for workouts display
const workoutsReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "add workout":
      const newState = state.map((el) => {
        return Object.assign({}, el);
      });
      newState.push(action.payload);
      return newState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const AthleteHomepage = () => {
  // state holding date value for calendar component
  const [value, setValue] = useState(new Date());
  // state holding modified date value for workout and modal components
  const [modifiedDate, setModifiedDate] = useState("");
  // state holding toggle and initial workout values for modal
  const [initialModalState, changeModalState] = useReducer(modalStateReducer, {
    open: false,
    workoutValue: "Bike",
  });
  // state for form fields
  const [workoutDetails, setWorkoutDetails] = useState("");
  const [athleteNotes, setAthleteNotes] = useState("");
  const [workoutComplete, setWorkoutComplete] = useState(false);
  // state for selected workout day
  // const [selectedWorkoutDay, setSelectedWorkoutDay] = useState([]);
  const [workouts, addWorkouts] = useReducer(workoutsReducer, []);
  // handle text input change
  const handleTextInputChange = (val, label) => {
    switch (label) {
      case "Enter workout details":
        setWorkoutDetails(val);
        break;
      case "Enter coach's notes":
        setCoachNotes(val);
        break;
      case "Enter athlete notes":
        setAthleteNotes(val);
        break;
      default:
        setWorkoutComplete((prevState) => !prevState);
    }
  };

  //reset form
  const resetForm = () => {
    // close modal
    changeModalState({ type: "changeModalVisibility" });
    // reset form fields
    setWorkoutDetails("");
    setAthleteNotes("");
    setWorkoutComplete(false);
  };

  // Handle form submission
  const handleSubmission = async (e) => {
    // prevent default refresh after form submission
    e.preventDefault();
    // declare obj to hold submission values sent to db, passing in required fields
    const data = {
      workoutValue: initialModalState.workoutValue,
      workoutDetails: workoutDetails,
      workoutComplete: workoutComplete,
      athleteNotes: athleteNotes,
    };
    // reset input form
    resetForm();
    // make a put request to the db to submit new workout details
    const res = await axios.post("/workouts", data);
    // add new workout to state obj
    addWorkouts({ type: "add workout", payload: res.data });
  };

  // handle modified date change on date value change
  useEffect(() => {
    setModifiedDate(value.toString().slice(0, 15));
  }, [value]);
  // handle date change on click within calendar component
  function handleDateChange(newValue) {
    setValue(newValue);
  }

  // deconstruct values from initialModalState to pass into context provider
  const { open, workoutValue } = initialModalState;
  return (
    // Provide child components with parent state
    <AthleteHomePageContext.Provider
      value={{
        value,
        modifiedDate,
        handleDateChange,
        changeModalState,
        open,
        workoutValue,
        workoutDetails,
        athleteNotes,
        handleTextInputChange,
        resetForm,
        handleSubmission,
        workoutComplete,
        workouts,
      }}
    >
      <Box>
        <ResponsiveAppBar />
        <Box
          sx={{
            minHeight: "calc(100vh - 210px)",
            marginBottom: "1.5rem",
            padding: "0 10px",
          }}
        >
          <h1>Training Schedule</h1>
          <Box className="GridContainer">
            <UpcomingEventsView />
            <Calendar />
            <WorkoutDetailsTile />
            <UpcomingCoachingSessions />
            <FormDialog />
            <PieChart />
            <BarChart />
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </AthleteHomePageContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AthleteHomepage;

const ResponsiveAppBar = () => {
  const [anchorElNav, setAnchorElNav] = useState(null);
  const [anchorElUser, setAnchorElUser] = useState(null);

  const handleOpenNavMenu = (event) => {
    setAnchorElNav(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleOpenUserMenu = (event) => {
    setAnchorElUser(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleCloseNavMenu = () => {
    setAnchorElNav(null);
  };

  const handleCloseUserMenu = (logout) => {
    if (logout) {
      const res = axios.get("/logout");
    }
    setAnchorElUser(null);
  };

  return (
    <AppBar
      sx={{ backgroundColor: "#EE6352", marginBottom: "1.5rem" }}
      position="static"
    >
      <Container maxWidth="xl">
        <Toolbar disableGutters>
          <FitnessCenterIcon
            sx={{ display: { xs: "none", md: "flex" }, mr: 1 }}
          />
          <Typography
            variant="h6"
            noWrap
            component="a"
            href="/"
            sx={{
              mr: 2,
              display: { xs: "none", md: "flex" },
              fontFamily: "monospace",
              fontWeight: 700,
              letterSpacing: ".3rem",
              color: "inherit",
              textDecoration: "none",
            }}
          >
            Sessions
          </Typography>

          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: "flex", md: "none" } }}>
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              aria-label="account of current user"
              aria-controls="menu-appbar"
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleOpenNavMenu}
              color="inherit"
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Menu
              id="menu-appbar"
              anchorEl={anchorElNav}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: "bottom",
                horizontal: "left",
              }}
              keepMounted
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: "top",
                horizontal: "left",
              }}
              open={Boolean(anchorElNav)}
              onClose={handleCloseNavMenu}
              sx={{
                display: { xs: "block", md: "none" },
              }}
            >
              {pages.map((page) => (
                <MenuItem key={page} onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                  <Typography textAlign="center">{page}</Typography>
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Menu>
          </Box>
          <FitnessCenterIcon
            sx={{ display: { xs: "flex", md: "none" }, mr: 1 }}
          />
          <Typography
            variant="h5"
            noWrap
            component="a"
            href=""
            sx={{
              mr: 2,
              display: { xs: "flex", md: "none" },
              flexGrow: 1,
              fontFamily: "monospace",
              fontWeight: 700,
              letterSpacing: ".3rem",
              color: "inherit",
              textDecoration: "none",
            }}
          >
            Sessions
          </Typography>
          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: "none", md: "flex" } }}>
            {pages.map((page) => (
              <Button
                key={page}
                onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}
                sx={{ my: 2, color: "#fff", display: "block" }}
              >
                {page}
              </Button>
            ))}
          </Box>

          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 0 }}>
            <Tooltip title="Open settings">
              <IconButton onClick={handleOpenUserMenu} sx={{ p: 0 }}>
                <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/2.jpg" />
              </IconButton>
            </Tooltip>
            <Menu
              sx={{ mt: "45px" }}
              id="menu-appbar"
              anchorEl={anchorElUser}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: "top",
                horizontal: "right",
              }}
              keepMounted
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: "top",
                horizontal: "right",
              }}
              open={Boolean(anchorElUser)}
              onClose={handleCloseUserMenu}
            >
              {settings.map((setting) =>
                setting === "Logout" ? (
                  <MenuItem
                    key={setting}
                    onClick={() => handleCloseUserMenu(true)}
                  >
                    <Typography textAlign="center">{setting}</Typography>
                  </MenuItem>
                ) : (
                  <MenuItem key={setting} onClick={handleCloseUserMenu}>
                    <Typography textAlign="center">{setting}</Typography>
                  </MenuItem>
                )
              )}
            </Menu>
          </Box>
        </Toolbar>
      </Container>
    </AppBar>
  );
};
export default ResponsiveAppBar;

//SCSS FILE BELOW:
//Font sizes
$fourteen-px: 0.875rem;
$fifteen-px: 0.9375rem;
$sixteen-px: 1rem;
$seventeen-px: 1.0625rem;
$eighteen-px: 1.125rem;
$nineteen-px: 1.1875rem;
$twenty-px: 1.25rem;
$twentyone-px: 1.3125rem;

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #414141;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

// LOGIN IN PAGE
.login-header-div {
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  height: 4rem;
  padding: 10px;
}

h5 {
  font-family: roboto;
  color: #414141;
}

.login-header {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: roboto;
}

.forgot-password {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: roboto;
  font-size: $fourteen-px;
  color: #035acc;
  display: block;
}

.sign-up-link {
  font-family: roboto;
  font-size: $fourteen-px;
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #035acc;
  }
}

hr {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

// ATHLETE HOME PAGE
// use for doing initial sketches - https://www.sketch.com/
.GridContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 0.3fr 0.3fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "events calendar calendar workout workout upcoming"
    "events monthly monthly yearly yearly upcoming";
  gap: $sixteen-px;
  .EventsContainer {
    grid-area: events;
  }

  .Calendar {
    grid-area: calendar;
  }

  .WorkoutDetails {
    grid-area: workout;
  }

  .PieChart {
    h3 {
      text-align: center;
    }

    grid-area: monthly;
  }

  .BarChart {
    grid-area: yearly;
  }

  .UpcomingCoachingSessions {
    grid-area: upcoming;
  }
}

.bottom-nav {
  display: grid !important;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  justify-items: center;
}

// MEDIA QUERIES FOR RESPONSIVE MAIN GRID
@media only screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
  .GridContainer {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas:
      "calendar workout"
      "events upcoming"
      "monthly yearly";
  }
  .bottom-nav {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    justify-items: center;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 870px) {
  .GridContainer {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas:
      "calendar"
      "workout"
      "upcoming"
      "events"
      "monthly"
      "yearly";
  }

  .bottom-nav {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    justify-items: center;
  }
}
```

Github repo: [https://github.com/jpettis1/Solo-project.git](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include the `AthleteHomepage` component code and the CSS/styling that is applied to it as part of your [mcve]?

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, yes! I have added the code for the AthleteHomepage as well as the navbar (<ResponsiveAppBar/>). Also, the custom styling for the components are defined within the sx props. I do have an additional scss file for grid and some additional styling for my login page. I have included that as well.

Answer (score 0):

After troubleshooting for quite some time I have found a solution. It appears that the third-party library I was using for my calendar component (Material-UI Pickers) was clashing with other Mui components, causing rendering issues (code duplication and missing code) in my application when implementing react router. The simplest solution I came up with was to use the static date picker from Mui date pickers instead of the third-party Material-UI Pickers calendar component. Still not quite sure why this was the case. Initially, I went into my Webpack and Babel configs to ensure that I configured my settings for optimization while in development mode and ensuring that I was set up to avoid code duplication via tree shaking. I am still new to development, so I am not sure if my thinking within this realm made sense, but this is a topic that came up within Mui's docs.